# How to make overlay not hidden under pad area

Tags: ffmpeg

i have the following command where i want overlay two images above image

```
 String command = '-y -i $backgroundImage1 -i $overlayImage1 -i $overlayImage2  -filter_complex '
                  '"[1]scale=600:600[i1];'
                  '[2]scale=600:600[i2];'
                  '[0][i1]overlay=1200:1200[01];'
                  '[01][i2]overlay=800:800'
                  ',pad=width=iw:height=ih+1000:x=0:y=0:color=black'
                  '" $outPutPath';
```

Now i notice if i position one of the overlay to be within the black pad area that i made so it be hidden behind it , how to solve, so the overlay on top pad ?

if anyone could help so kindly edit my full command because i just start to learn `ffmpeg` , thanks